# How to Raise upstart access?

Tags: ubuntu, server, upstart

My project run when i use `./launch.sh` command in terminal.
But with upstart not run, i try to run it i get this on upstart log:

`Operation not permitted`

It seems like little access,
My upstart script:

```
description "upstart script"

respawn
respawn limit 15 5

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on shutdown

setuid root
exec /bin/sh /root/bot/launch.sh
```

This script works for my previous project which requires less access, but do not currently work that requires more access.